# Connect to multiple database schemas in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, schema

In my spring boot application I am using Oracle as the database.
The database has different schemas.
I have a requirement, to list all the schemas and connect to the database using that schema in a loop and do some query on the tables.
I have seen some blogs to connect to different schemas by defining datasource in application.properties.
I don't want to do that becuase I have around 40+ schemas defined and I don't want to define those many datasources.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a better solution to connect with one account (with read permission to all the schema's) to the database and use a simple SQL query to fetch all the schema's.

If you know the schema's you can build custom SQL queries to fetch the data from each schema. (select * from SCHEMA1.sometable)

I think it's not a good idea to create connection for each schema in your situation.

Comment: sure, let me try that